# Como saber se uma janela JDialog esta aberta ou fechada?

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

Queria saber, como eu posso saber se uma tela, no meu caso um `JDialog` está aberto. Existe algum evento ou maneira de saber isto?

*Obs: Eu vou utilizar essa "informação" como parâmetro em uma condição, por exemplo, se tela fechada faça tal coisa.*

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class FecharTela extends JFrame {

    private JButton botao = new JButton("+");
    private DialogX x = new DialogX();

    public FecharTela() {
        setTitle("Teste");
        add(montaTela());
        setSize(500, 400);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private JComponent montaTela() {
        JPanel jpMontaTela = new JPanel();
        jpMontaTela.add(botao);

        botao.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {

            x.setVisible(true);
        });

        return jpMontaTela;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FecharTela ft = new FecharTela();
        ft.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class DialogX extends JDialog {

    public DialogX() {
        setSize(300, 300);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        add(new JLabel("Erro no campo .."));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar os métodos [`isVisible()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#isVisible()) e/ou [`isDisplayable()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#isDisplayable()) herdados da classe `Component`  para checar se a janela já foi aberta ou não.